# Autocomplete in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, autocomplete, ionic-framework

I am new to `ionic`, I have started creating application on it. For last few days, I have been searching for `autocomplete` in ionic. I found a *codepan* but it's not that simple one. I need autocomplete just like `JqueryUI` provides.

Comment: was my answer useful for you?

Answer (score 3):

There is a cool `directive`, Uptil now it's acceptable solution with 155 *s on github repo, try it:

[Ionic directive - Autocomplete](https://github.com/guylabs/ion-autocomplete)

[Ionic directive - Autocomplete Website](https://guylabs.ch/2015/02/18/ionic-autocomplete-project/)

Comment: Thanks for using this directive ;). I hope it fits your needs and if you have any issues or feedback please create an issue in the github repository.

Comment: i tried to use it, but it returns object instead of name in search options while typing. i used http.get(url) in callback function return.

Comment: @AkashSaxena it looks like solution is working and you need to read docs again to show proper value on display `item-view-value-key="child.name"` see this link https://github.com/guylabs/ion-autocomplete#using-expressions-in-value-keys

Comment: @ZeeshanHassanMemon, thanks. I tried                                        <input ion-autocomplete type="text" readonly="readonly" class="ion-autocomplete" autocomplete="off" max-selected-items="1" ng-model="corporation" items-method="autoCompleteMethod(query)" item-value-key ="name" item-view-value-key="name" /> , but this only displays the list of items and do not live filtered data. Do i need to pass array variable from controller in this input type?

Comment: @ZeeshanHassanMemon My callback function is like :                             $scope.autoCompleteMethod = function (query, isInitializing) {
    if(query){
      return $http.get(baseurl+'corportaions');
    }else{
      return [query];
    }
  }

Comment: @AkashSaxena share the type/structure of data returned by your $http call and the html you have written for autocomplete display

Comment: @ZeeshanHassanMemon using $http.get(url) returns data as
[{"name":"Avon","id":4},{"name":"Hero","id":5},{"name":"Reliance","id":6}]
Html Tag
<input ion-autocomplete type="text" readonly="readonly" class="ion-autocomplete" autocomplete="off" max-selected-items="1" ng-model="corporation" items-method="autoComplete(query)" item-value-key ="name" item-view-value-key="name" />
Callback function:
$scope.autoComplete = function (query, isInitializing) {
    if(query){
      return $http.get(baseurl+'financial_corportaions');
    }else{
      return [query];
    }
  }

Answer (score 1):

If you want an autocomplete like bootstrap typehead instead modal autocomplete of Guylabs you have [allmighty-autocomplete](https://github.com/JustGoscha/allmighty-autocomplete). It is for angular, but I forked it and made some changes to fit it in Ionic.

Works fine but there is one issue if you put before a text input in a form.
You can see that issue here: [Clicks on div over an input in Ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35598846/clicks-on-div-over-an-input-in-ionic)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ionic 2+ and Angular 2+ then I recommend [ionic4-auto-complete](https://github.com/jrquick17/ionic4-auto-complete).

See a [demo here](https://ionic4-auto-complete.jrquick.com).

Answer (score 0):

**You can try with this.**

1. Install bower: `npm install -g bower`
2. Then, run this on the project root: 
   `bower install ionic-autocomplete`
3. Add this attribute on the view

   `<input type="text" ng-model="search" ionic-autocomplet="{item:myItems, onSelect: doSomthing}" />`
4. And finally, add this to your controller:

   `.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope){
      $scope.doSomthing = function(item) {
        console.log('The selected item is: '+item);
     }
    });`

> Reference : [Bower library](https://libraries.io/bower/ionic-autocomplete)
>
> Github : [Example on Github](https://github.com/sn0opr/ionic-autocomplete)

*I hope this helps.*